# Configure Yakuake Terminal Separator Color?

Tags: terminal, kde, colors, debugging, kubuntu

I am using KDE 5 with Yakuake as my drop-down terminal, on Kubuntu. I am now encountering a [documented bug](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=373428), which is that the separators between multiple terminals only show on a black background. Screenshots attached:

[image]
[image]

My diagnosis here is that the color profile configuration options for some reason don't affect the color of the terminal separator. (This used to be the case in KDE 4). I've tried changing skins, editing my Shell profile, etc. It now seems to me that surely the color of the separator line must be hardcoded somewhere, and that I can change this color? Does anyone know where I can find this?

Comment: This should be configurable! Did you find a solution?

Comment: Actually I have the opposite problem: the divider is dark for me but I would like it to be light! So maybe it's influenced by some theme settings after all.